Debian package for Cassandra 3.11.17 is not available in official repository
While fix release 3.11.17 for Cassandra 3.11.x was announced a while back, the latest version of the Debian package at the official Debian repository as per https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/cassandra-deb/dists/311x/main/binary-amd64/Packages is still 3.11.16.
Package: cassandra
Version: 3.11.16

Is there any specific reason for that?
Thank you.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I can confirm that the repository is out of date for whatever reason.
I've logged CASSANDRA-19681 to get this issue investigated and hopefully resolved quickly. Thanks again. Cheers!
UPDATE - It seems the publish job failed but it didn't get picked up. There is an open ticket to address this (CASSANDRA-19561).
In any case, the issue has been resolved and the package is now available from the repository (credit to Brandon Williams).

Thank you for the help!

I've posted an update in my answer. This has now been fixed. Cheers!

I can confirm that package is now available for installation. Appreciate your help!
